# Qual a interface evento que é recebido pelo evento beforeinstallprompt?

Tags: angular, typescript, pwa

Bom adicionei um botão de instalação do site para facilitar o acesso dos usuários. Estou usando o `Angular 15`.

O `lint` está me manda o seguinte erro de tipagem:

```
 Unexpected any. Specify a different type
```

O erro acontece pois declarei a variável `deferredPrompt`como `any`, o problema é que não faço ideia de como tipar ela.

Vou postar o código que esta funcional, porém quero resolver esse erro.

```
  public deferredPrompt: any;

  ngOnInit(): void {
     window.addEventListener('beforeinstallprompt', (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        this.deferredPrompt = event;
      });
    }

    installPwa(): void {
      this.deferredPrompt.prompt();
      this.deferredPrompt.userChoice.then((choiceResult: { outcome: string }) => {
        if (choiceResult.outcome === 'accepted') {
          this.sucess();
        } else {
          this.error();
        }
        this.deferredPrompt = null;
      });
    }
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51503754/typescript-type-beforeinstallpromptevent Acredito que a dúvida seja a mesma, pelo menos me ajudou.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Em vez de `any`, use `unknown` ou `never`

### `unknown`

Forçará você a afirmar explicitamente e com segurança que o tipo está correto.

### `never`

É útil ao instanciar parâmetros de tipo genérico dos quais você não precisa saber o tipo.

Você pode também desligar o aviso do `any` editando o arquivo `.eslintrc.*` (exemplo: `.eslintrc.cjs`, `.eslintrc.json`), que contêm as regras, deve estar semelhante a isto:

```js
module.exports = {
  "rules": {
    "@typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any": "warn"
  }
};
```

Remova a linha `"@typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any": "warn"` que você não irá mais ter essa regra no seu *lint* ou apenas troque `"warn"` por `"off"`.

Mesmo existindo a possibilidade de desabilitar o erro globalmente, ainda o ideal é usar `unknown` ou `never` conforme cada caso.

Respondendo ao titulo da pergunta:

> <strike>Tipagem da variável que recebe o prompt do Pwa;</strike>
>
> Qual a interface evento que é recebido pelo evento beforeinstallprompt?

O [`BeforeInstallPromptEvent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/BeforeInstallPromptEvent) é a interface do evento disparado pelo `beforeinstallprompt`, você pode experimentar usar essa interface no seu código, não cheguei a testar se isso faz parte dos tipos do typescript, mas por [não está documentado](https://microsoft.github.io/PowerBI-JavaScript/modules/_node_modules_typedoc_node_modules_typescript_lib_lib_dom_d_.html) provavelmente vai causar erro no seu código, já que [`beforeinstallprompt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/beforeinstallprompt_event) é **experimental** ainda (2023-02-25).

Comment: Optei por desligar `"@typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any": ["off"]` no `.eslintrc.json`.

Comment: @HugoBorges ok, adicionei o [detalhe a resposta na revisão](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/577891/revisions).